# How to structure content that is related to a <dl> but doesn't necessarily belong inside the list itself?

Tags: html, html-lists

Transitioning department docs to a paperless system. Trying to understand the best way to set up certain areas of content. Displaying basic demographics I've found posts suggesting using data description list as such,

```
<dl>
  <dt>name</dt>
  </dd>user name</dd>

  <dt>address</dt>
  <dd>user address</dd>
</dl>
```

Some sections require disclaimers which seem that they would best fall into a paragraph element making the code do something like this...

```
<p>this is how your name will appear... for modifications go to...</p>
<dt>name</dt>
<dd>username</dd>
```

I don't believe paragraph elements are allowed within a description list though. Would breaking up my list into two separate lists be a better way to go about this so the data is still represented properly?